# MySQL DB Upload Failure & Undefined Offset Error

Tags: php, mysql

Hellos.

Assist me with two queries in the file below intended to upload CSV files

- Failing to upload to a MySQL without logging errors (Am I missing folder/file permissions?)
- "Undefined offset" error from anything after column 10 in CSV (Is there a limit I declared unknowingly?)

Thank You.

```
if(isset($_POST['import'])){

    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 
                    'text/comma-separated-values', 
                    'application/octet-stream', 
                    'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
                    'application/x-csv', 
                    'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 
                    'application/csv', 
                    'application/excel', 
                    'application/vnd.msexcel', 
                    'text/plain');

    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) 
        && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes))
    {

        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

            fgetcsv($csvFile);

            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){

                $ColID   = $line[0];
                $Col02   = $line[1];
                $Col03   = $line[2];
                $Col04   = $line[3];
                $Col05   = $line[4];
                $Col06   = $line[5];
                $Col07   = $line[6];
                $Col08   = $line[7];
                $Col09   = $line[8];
                $Col010  = $line[9];
                $Col0n   = $line[10];

                $prevQuery = "SELECT id 
                            FROM table_name 
                            WHERE ColID = '".$line[0]."'";
                $prevResult = $db->query($prevQuery);

                if($prevResult){
                    if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                        $db->query("UPDATE table_name 
                            SET ColHdg02 = '".$Col02."', 
                            ColHdg03 = '".$Col03."', 
                            ColHdg04 = '".$Col04."', 
                            ColHdg05 = '".$Col05."', 
                            ColHdg06 = '".$Col06."', 
                            ColHdg07 = '".$Col07."', 
                            ColHdg08 = '".$Col08."', 
                            ColHdg09 = '".$Col09."', 
                            ColHdg010 = '".$Col010."', 
                            ColHdg0n = '".$Col0n."' 
                        WHERE ColIDHdg = '".$ColID."'");
                    } else{
                        $db->query("INSERT INTO table_name 
                                (ColIDHdg, ColHdg02, ColHdg03, ColHdg04, 
                                ColHdg05, ColHdg06, ColHdg07, ColHdg08, 
                                ColHdg09, ColHdg010, ColHdg0n) 
                            VALUES ('".$ColID."', '".$Col02."', '".$Col03."',
                                    '".$Col04."', '".$Col05."', '".$Col06."', 
                                    '".$Col07."', '".$Col08."', '".$Col09."', 
                                    '".$Col010."', '".$Col0n."')");
                    } 
                }
            }
            fclose($csvFile);
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: _Failing to upload to a MySQL without logging errors_ **What errors** Always show us any errors (All the Errors, not a summary) you are getting, they help us to understand your problem.

Comment: _"Undefined offset" error from anything after column 10_ Then I think you also need to show us at least a few lines from your csv file.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, my sample CSV file had entry errors. No more "Undefined Offset" error.
"Failing to upload to MySQL without logging errors" i.e. the CSV data is not loaded into the table and no errors are logged.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an Undefined offset, for your example please check if the number of items on $line is 11 or more.

```
if (count($line) > 10) {
    $ColID   = $line[0];
    $Col02  = $line[1];
    $Col03  = $line[2];
    $Col04 = $line[3];
    $Col05   = $line[4];
    $Col06  = $line[5];
    $Col07 = $line[6];
    $Col08   = $line[7];
    $Col09 = $line[8];
    $Col010  = $line[9];
    $Col0n  = $line[10];

    $prevQuery = "SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE ColID = '" . $line[0] . "'";
    $prevResult = $db->query($prevQuery);

    if ($prevResult) {
        if ($prevResult->num_rows > 0) {
            $db->query("UPDATE table_name SET ColHdg02 = '" . $Col02 . "', ColHdg03 = '" . $Col03 . "', ColHdg04 = '" . $Col04 . "', ColHdg05 = '" . $Col05 . "', ColHdg06 = '" . $Col06 . "', ColHdg07 = '" . $Col07 . "', ColHdg08 = '" . $Col08 . "', ColHdg09 = '" . $Col09 . "', ColHdg010 = '" . $Col010 . "', ColHdg0n = '" . $Col0n . "' WHERE ColIDHdg = '" . $ColID . "'");
        } else {
            $db->query("INSERT INTO table_name (ColIDHdg, ColHdg02, ColHdg03, ColHdg04, ColHdg05, ColHdg06, ColHdg07, ColHdg08, ColHdg09, ColHdg010, ColHdg0n) VALUES ('" . $ColID . "', '" . $Col02 . "', '" . $Col03 . "', '" . $Col04 . "', '" . $Col05 . "', '" . $Col06 . "', '" . $Col07 . "', '" . $Col08 . "', '" . $Col09 . "', '" . $Col010 . "', '" . $Col0n . "')");
        }
    }
}
```